# best solution to show/hide a form which is running a thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a main form and an analyze form. Main form has a button named "show analyze form".
Analyze form will run a thread. It also has a button named "Work In Background" that will hide analyze form.
When thread's process finished, analyze form should be shown (whether "Work In Background" button clicked or not) and some controls in the analyze form should be enabled.
I have some code to describe my efforts but it does not work properly.
So what is the problem, and what is the best solution to accomplish this? Is there any sample or article discuss about this?

```
public partial class frmAnalyze : Form
{
    Form owner;

    public frmAnalyze(frmMain owner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Owner = owner;
     }

    private void btnAnalyze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            btnBackgroundWork.Enabled = true;

            Analyzer analizer = new Analyzer();
            analizer.OnAnalyzeCallback += new AnalyzeCallbackHandler(analizer_OnAnalyzeCallback);
            analizer.OnAnalyzeProgress += new 
     }

    void analizer_OnAnalyzeCallback(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke(new AnalyzeCallbackHandler(analizer_OnAnalyzeCallback), sender, arg);
        else
        {
            Owner.Invoke(new AnalyzeCallbackHandler(((frmMain)Owner).ShowfrmAnalyze), sender, arg);

            SomeControl.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

this is weird that InvokeRequired always return false
and this is main form

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private void biAnalyze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmAnalyze = new frmAnalyze(this);
        frmAnalyze.ShowDialog();
    }

    internal void ShowfrmAnalyze(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmAnalyze.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is 'not working correctly'?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) thread in the AnalyzerForm.

You can show the AnalyzerForm backk when the [BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onrunworkercompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which is executed in the main thread.